# SqlBulkCopy with calculated field

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I would like to use the SQLBulkCopy class to push insert data into a table. However, I am hitting a wall with trying to allow the mapping functionality to accept a calculated field. Example trying to populate a field in my destination table called Age which is a calculated value from my source table (2015(current year) - date of birth year).

Comment: Please post the relevant code. The question doesn't make a lot of sense as it is. Calculated fields aren't writeable by definition - just don't add a mapping for them. Perhaps you mean that you want to store a *calculated* value? How did you try to do this? Did you try to create a calculated field in the DataTable or did you add the calculation in the `SELECT` statement you used to pull the data?

Comment: Also note that storing an Age field is typically a bad idea - you'd have to update all rows each year. Using a calculated, or creating a view on top of the table is the typical way to do this.

Comment: Hi I am trying to compute a column for my destination table that would 1) Be composed of multiple columns from my source table  2) Contain a calculation based on a column from the source table. I have given the age example just to illustrate the issue i am having.

Comment: Define the calculated column, but don't insert anything into it via SqlBulkCopy. Don't even map it. Once you insert the appropriate data into the columns that the calculated columns depend on, the calculated columns will.....be calculated.